# How do i add the complete data from table 1 from workbook1 to the end of table 2 in another workbook2 using Excel VBA macros?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables

I wrote the following code from here and there:

```
Workbooks(location1).Worksheets("Lab Bench").ListObjects("ItemsSummary").Range("ItemsSummary[#All]").Select 'ItemsSummary is the name of the table, it has 18 columns


lRow = Workbooks(location2).Worksheets(Sheet1).ListObjects("ItemsSummary").ListRows.Count


LO.ListRows(lRow).Range.Select    'Select last row in a table
BottomOfTable = ActiveCell.Row    'Row number of the worksheet


'Inserts a new table 1 row below the desired table
ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("C" & BottomOfTable + 1, "H" & BottomOfTable + 1), , xlNo).Name = "ItemsSummary"
```

This code throws in this error: Subscript out of range (Error 9)

I am new to coding and i would appreciate any help with this. Please suggest any better way to do this. I have scratched half my scalp with this